# Azure Devops Moq Framework, how to resolve database dependecy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My code is old and I have a hard dependency on database. Project is divided into service, business and database layer. Basically database layer is entity framework. The issue is that whenever I tried to run Moq test it try to connect to database. Can some one please advise how can I resolve database dependency.

MoqFramework unit test

```
public async Task GetEmployees()
{

    IQueryable<Employee> employees= new List<Employee>()
    {
        new Employee(){ D = 1, Name = "AAAA" },
         new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "BBB" }
    }.AsQueryable();

    using(var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        mock.Mock<IDatalayerClass>().Setup(x => x.GetEmployees()).Returns(employees);                
        var cls = mock.Create<BusinessLayerClass>();
       var acutal =  cls.Employees();
      ///Assert ///
    }           
    
}
```

Data Layer code -

```
public DataLayerClass : IDatalayerClass
    public DataLayerClass() 
    {            
        this.entities = new DataHubEntities();
    }

    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {          
        //entity framework code to get employee from database
        return Employees;
    }
```

Business Layer -

```
 public BusinessLayerClass() : IBusinessLayerClass  
    public BusinessLayerClass()
    {
        layer  = new DataLayerClass() ;  //Hard dependency on data class
    }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> employees()
    {
       
        IQueryable<Employee> query = this.layer.GetEmployees(); //data layer method
        IEnumerable<Empolyee> emploees = query.Take(employeeIDs).ToList();           
        return employees;
    }
```

Service Layer -

```
public HttpResponseMessage Employees()
{     
            
    BusinessLayerClass bl = new BusinessLayerClass();
    IEnumerable<Employee> employees = bl.Employees();
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employees);         
            
    return response;
}
```

Comment: `this.entities = new DataHubEntities();` looks like this line tries to connect to database. Do you need this line in mock class?

Comment: if this is Entity Framework Core, you can use an in-memory database instead of mocking everything out.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Have a look at Effort https://entityframework-effort.net/

Answer (score 1):

There is too much tight coupling to allow for isolated testing.

The Business layer should explicitly depend on the data layer's abstraction via constructor injection

```
public BusinessLayerClass() : IBusinessLayerClass {
    private readonly IDatalayerClass layer;
    
    public BusinessLayerClass(IDatalayerClass layer) {
        this.layer  = layer
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees() {
    
        //...
        
        IQueryable<Employee> query = layer.GetEmployees(); //data layer method
        IEnumerable<Empolyee> emploees = query.Take(employeeIDs).ToList();
        return employees;
    }
}
```

So now in order to test the business layer class in isolation, the dependencies can be mocked and injected into the subject under test.

```
public void Should_GetEmployees() {
    // Arrange
    IQueryable<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>() {
        new Employee() { D = 1, Name = "AAAA" },
        new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "BBB" }
    }.AsQueryable();

    using(var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        mock.Mock<IDatalayerClass>().Setup(x => x.GetEmployees()).Returns(employees);
        BusinessLayerClass subject = mock.Create<BusinessLayerClass>();
        
        // Act
        var acutal =  subject.Employees();
        
        // Assert 
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

The service layer should also depend on the business layer abstraction via injection instead of manually initializing `BusinessLayerClass`

Using dependency injection, the implementations will be injected at run-time.

Comment: thanks @Nkosi. it's like changing main project classes and retest everything. Does it make sense here to use property injection instead of constructor injection. In property injection , I can populate default value if dependency if not pass from outside